# PHP: How to set timezone correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, monolog

I want to use Laravel to develop an API for my app, and had installed the Homestead, but when I use command "php artisan make:model test"
the following warning is displayed:

> PHP Warning:  date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on
>   the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to
>   select your timezone. in
>   /Users/liyanan/Code/Laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php
>   on line 311

I have tried to change the php.ini file in /ect like this

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = ‘Asia/Tokyo’
```

And change Laravel's app.php like this

```
'timezone' => ‘Asia/Tokyo’,
```

And Laravel's Logger.php like this

```
    date_default_timezone_set(‘Asia/Tokyo’);
    if (!static::$timezone) {
        static::$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get() ?: ‘Asia/Tokyo’);
    }

    // php7.1+ always has microseconds enabled, so we do not need this hack
    if ($this->microsecondTimestamps && PHP_VERSION_ID < 70100) {
        $ts = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%.6F', microtime(true)), static::$timezone);
    } else {
        $ts = new \DateTime(null, static::$timezone);
    }
    $ts->setTimezone(static::$timezone);
```

But it did not work, hope somebody could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: you seem to use `smartquotes` ... in both files.  Are you or this is a copy-paste error ?

Comment: definitelly has to be only an issue with quotes, apart from them it looks good

Comment: Not sure if the quote type might be it.  Try changing the quote after the o in Tokyo to a ' instead of ’

Try changing 

    date_default_timezone_set(‘Asia/Tokyo’); 
to 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

Comment: Yes ,looks like the  quotes are problem,but I have replece them with ',but yet did not work,so the code is right?